# C++ library for getting the JPEG image size

Tags: c++, c, jpeg

Do you know any good imaging library for getting the size of a JPEG image in memory? I only need to get the size of the image. If possible, I'd prefer it be header-only.
It seems boost::gil requires a third-party library (libjpeg) if I remember well.

Comment: boost::gil is header-only, as per its [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/gil/doc/html/giltutorial.html#InstallSec)

Comment: @diw no, http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/html/jpeg__dynamic__io_8hpp.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using following code we can verify that a given file is jpeg image file and we can also get image size.

```
int width, height;
FILE *image;
int size, i = 0;
unsigned char *data;

image =fopen("file_name","rb");  // open JPEG image file
if(!image){
   printf("Unable to open image \n");
}
fseek(image,  0,  SEEK_END);
size = ftell(image);
fseek(image,  0,  SEEK_SET);
data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
fread(data, 1, size, image);
/* verify valid JPEG header */
if(data[i] == 0xFF && data[i + 1] == 0xD8 && data[i + 2] == 0xFF && data[i + 3] == 0xE0) {
     i += 4;
     /* Check for null terminated JFIF */
     if(data[i + 2] == 'J' && data[i + 3] == 'F' && data[i + 4] == 'I' && data[i + 5] == 'F' && data[i + 6] == 0x00) {
         while(i < size) {
             i++;
             if(data[i] == 0xFF){
                 if(data[i+1] == 0xC0) {
                     height = data[i + 5]*256 + data[i + 6];
                     width = data[i + 7]*256 + data[i + 8];
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 } 
 fclose(image);
```